# Get searched value while typing under multiselect

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

I am trying to get typed value in select using jQuery under my Laravel project but unfortunately I am unable to get it. I am using library Searchable Option List(SOL) for multiselection.

Here is my html code:

```
{{ Form::select('select_students[]', $studentList, $studentIds, ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'multi-select']) }}
```

Script code:

```
 $('.multi-select').searchableOptionList({
    maxHeight: '250px',
    showSelectAll: true,
    showSelectionBelowList: true
 });
```

Please help me out to get typed value. My purpose is to use that value in another input text box.

Here is SOL library link
https://pbauerochse.github.io/searchable-option-list/configuration.html

If you need any info, please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+filter+searchableOptionsList+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You can add `$(document).on('input', '.sol-input-container input', function(){console.log($(this).val())})` this code and check if the value is printing when you typed in side input-box

Comment: how about using the select2 js library ?